# Repeated transformation of function yields identity

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

For a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ in the Schwartz class, define $$Tf(y)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)e^{-ixy}dx$$ I want to show that $T^4f(y)=f(y)$. But plugging in the formula of $T$ four times just gives a quadruple integral, so probably not the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for the inverse Fourier transform is the same as that of $T$ but with $e^{-ixy}$ replaced by $e^{ixy}$.  Thus $T(Tf)(y) = f(-y)$.  Apply $T^2$ again and you get $f(y)$.